# Integration by parts finding reduction formula

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the question below to find it's reduction formula. i have no issue with solving everything down to it's last power but have no idea how does the reduction formula works? Any tips on getting it started?
$$\int_0^{pi/2} x^5\cos x dx$$
$$\int_0^{pi/2} x^5\sin x dx$$

$$\int_0^{pi/2} x^n\cos x dx$$
$$\int_0^{pi/2} x^n\sin x dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Do integration by parts with integrating trigonometric part and differentiating $x^5$ like below.

$$\int x^5\cos xdx=x^5\sin x - 5\int x^4 \sin x dx$$ 
$$\int x^5\sin xdx=-x^5\cos x + 5\int x^4 \cos x dx$$

Then try integration by parts once again.

$$\int x^5\cos xdx=x^5\sin x - 5x^4\cos x + 20\int x^3 \cos x dx$$
$$\int x^5\sin xdx=-x^5\cos x + 5x^4\sin x - 20\int x^3 \sin x dx$$

By trying this at $x^n\cos x$ or $x^n \sin x$, you can easily get the reduction formula.

$$I_n=\int x^n \sin{x} dx,\qquad J_n=\int x^n \cos{x} dx$$
$$I_n=-x^n \cos{x} + nx^{n-1} \sin{x} - n(n-1) I_{n-2}$$
$$J_n=x^n \sin{x} + nx^{n-1} \cos{x} - n(n-1) J_{n-2}$$

Comment: i don't have an issue with integrating down everything like i mentioned above. just don't have an idea to convert it to a reducton formula. also there isn't a negative sign

Comment: Sorry, I confused the sign. Try to integrate by parts once again after that.

Comment: i have no issue solving the functions with integration by parts. how to covert it into reduction formula is a question i asked

Comment: Try to integrate by parts once again as I edited the answer.

Comment: i need to prove the formula $$I_n=(\frac{pi}{2})^n-nJ(n-1)$$$$J_n=nA(n-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Another method to do these types of problems:

Note:

$$Re(x^5e^{ix})=Re(x^5(\cos x + i \sin x))$$

So:

$$Re \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^5e^{ix}dx$$

We can apply the Tanzanian method http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/tanzalin-method-for-easier-integration-by-parts-4339to get the antiderivative:

$$e^{i x} (120-120ix-60x^2+20ix^3+5x^4-ix^5)$$

So our integral:

$$=Re\left((e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}})(120-120i(\frac{\pi}{2})-60(\frac{\pi ^2}{4})+20i(\frac{\pi ^3}{8})+5(\frac{\pi ^4}{16})-i(\frac{\pi ^5}{32})\right)-120$$

But $e^{\frac{i \pi}{2}}=0+1i$

So

We just look at all the terms with the $i$'s and perform multiplication and that to simplify.

$$=-120+60\pi-5\frac{\pi ^3}{2}+\frac{\pi ^5}{32}$$

You can do the same for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ in the power of cosine. A almost identical method holds for cosine.